# PyQt 5 call a function without clicking in python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Hi guys im new in python and PyQt already im using PyQt 5 lib and already faced with really primary problem.

I want to call print function (or any other functions like this) with just cursor moving no clicking on that.

some thing like tooltips that not needed to click on any button.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to implement:

#### 1. customized button.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class HoverButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    hovered = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.hovered.emit()
        super(HoverButton, self).enterEvent(event)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        btn = HoverButton("Press me")
        btn.hovered.connect(self.onHovered)

        lay.addWidget(btn)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLineEdit())

    def onHovered(self):
        print("hovered")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### 2. eventFilter

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press me")
        self.btn.installEventFilter(self)

        lay.addWidget(self.btn)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLineEdit())

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj == self.btn and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverEnter:
            self.onHovered()
        return super(Widget, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    def onHovered(self):
        print("hovered")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thank you so much again i have another question 
how can i  change a pic by mouse hover?